langchain js does not show the retrieve data just show the ai response
I’m developing a chatbot that recommends products for online shopping. The goal is to input my product data into the chatbot and have it display relevant products in response to user queries. Below is the code I’m currently using:

import { MemoryVectorStore } from "langchain/vectorstores/memory";
import { OpenAIEmbeddings, ChatOpenAI } from "@langchain/openai";
import { PromptTemplate } from "@langchain/core/prompts";
import { StringOutputParser } from "@langchain/core/output_parsers";
import Env from '@ioc:Adonis/Core/Env'
import fs from 'fs';
import { RunnableSequence, RunnablePassthrough } from "@langchain/core/runnables";
// import {} from 'langchain/text_splitter'

class Ai {
    private async embed_product() {
        const rawData = fs.readFileSync('products.json', 'utf-8');
        const data = JSON.parse(rawData);
        const products = data.products;

        let product_docs: string[] = [];
        for (let product of products) {
            let tags = product.tags.toString();
            let product_doc = `This is a ${product.title}. Its description is ${product.body_html} and its vendor is ${product.vendor} and its product_type is ${product.product_type}. This product has these tags: ${tags}.`;

            let options = product.options;
            let variants_doc = "";
            for (let variant of product.variants) {
                if (!variant.available) {
                    continue;
                }
                let variant_doc = "(";
                for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                    variant_doc += `${options[i].name}: ${variant["option" + (i + 1)]}, `;
                }
                let s = `price: ${variant.price}, weight: ${variant.grams})`;
                variant_doc += s;
                variants_doc += variant_doc;
            }
            product_doc += `\nThis product is available in these variants:\n${variants_doc}`;
            product_docs.push(product_doc);
        }
        const embeddings = new OpenAIEmbeddings()

        const vstore = await MemoryVectorStore.fromTexts(product_docs, [], embeddings);
        return vstore;
    }

    public async agent(question: string) {
        let llm = new ChatOpenAI({
            model: "gpt-4",
            openAIApiKey: Env.get('OPENAI_API_KEY')
        });
        const vectorstore = await this.embed_product()
        const retriver = vectorstore.asRetriever({ searchType: 'similarity' })
        function combineDocs(docs) {
            return {
                combinedText: docs.map(doc => doc.pageContent).join('\n\n'),
                rawDocs: docs
            };
        }

        const qtemplate = `Given a question, convert it to a standalone question.
        question: {question} standalone question:`

        // System message template
        const template = `
        You are a clothing sales assistant chat bot for Digikala online shopping. Answer customers' questions and guide them appropriately. Use available tools to retrieve relevant information when necessary.
When answering, follow these guidelines:
1. If the given information is unrelated to the question or you do not know the answer, honestly say, "I do not know the answer to this question."
2. Be polite, friendly, accurate, concise, and add a bit of humor.

Here is the format for your response:
question: {question}
context: {context}
answer:
- Your answer here.
- If applicable, include product details from the retrieved context.`

        const answerPrompt = PromptTemplate.fromTemplate(template)
        const questionPrompt = PromptTemplate.fromTemplate(qtemplate)

        const questionChain = questionPrompt.pipe(llm).pipe(new StringOutputParser)
        const retriverChain = RunnableSequence.from([
            preResult => preResult.standalone_question,
            retriver,
            combineDocs,
        ])

        const answerChain = answerPrompt.pipe(llm).pipe(new StringOutputParser())

        const chain = RunnableSequence.from([
            {
                standalone_question: questionChain,
                original_input: new RunnablePassthrough()
            },
            {
                context: retriverChain,
                question: ({ original_input }) => original_input.question
            },
            answerChain
        ])

        const response = await chain.invoke({ question });
        return response;
    }
}
export default new Ai()


it just show the ai response not including the products that I specify in retriever
I want to show the response of ai and the products in chat bot but I get just the ai response.
